# Azure SearchIndexClient - no attribute 'IndexDocuments'

Tags: python, azure-cognitive-search

I am going nuts.
I am trying to upload documents into my Azure Search Index using Python.

When I use

```
from azure.search.documents.indexes import SearchIndexClient
```

```
#Initialize Azure Cognitive Search client
```

```
documents = [
    {
        'id': '1',
        'url': 'bla',
        'title': 'bla',
        'body': 'bla'
    }
]
result = search_client.index_documents(documents)
```

and run that in VSCode, I get
`AttributeError: 'SearchIndexClient' object has no attribute 'index_documents'`

I found different documentation and does tried IndexDocuemtns, UploadDocuemnts, upload_documents all with the same issue.
What do I mess up?
Thank you
Roger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because there's no method called `index_documents` in `SearchIndexClient` class. It is actually available in [`SearchClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-search-documents/azure.search.documents.searchclient?view=azure-python). You would need to get an instance of `SearchClient` using [`get_search_client()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-search-documents/azure.search.documents.indexes.searchindexclient?view=azure-python#azure-search-documents-indexes-searchindexclient-get-search-client) method and then call `index_documents()` method.

Please try the following code:

```
from azure.search.documents.indexes import SearchIndexClient

#Initialize Azure Cognitive Search index client

search_client = search_index_client.get_search_client('your-index-name')

documents = [
    {
        'id': '1',
        'url': 'bla',
        'title': 'bla',
        'body': 'bla'
    }
]

result = search_client.index_documents(documents)
```